# Increasing Convex Function Increasing Second Derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be increasing and convex on a certain interval. Then, $f’’(x)\geq 0$ on this interval. I was wondering if it could be further said that $f’’(x)$ is increasing (or at least non-decreasing) on this interval.

Comment: Constant functions are convex.

Comment: What if $f$ is convex and strictly increasing?

Comment: @CyclotomicField the question asks about an increasing function.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw linear functions are also convex and can be strictly increasing.

Comment: In either case, wouldn’t the second derivative still be non-decreasing?

Comment: Yes, they would be non-decreasing in the constant and linear cases as the second derivative is always zero. I mention them only to encourage you to check trivial cases since they often provide counter examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just pointed it out as the linear examples don’t provide a counter-example for saying the second derivative is non-decreasing.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes.  But I was addressing someone who mentioned constant functions, because the question doesn’t ask about constant functions. The question asks about strictly increasing functions.

Answer (score -2):

No it can not be said. The second derivative gives you strength of the curvature but since a convex function can have decrasing curvature too the answer is no.

Imagine x^2 beeing cutoff at 1 and then continuoued with constant increase. Then f''(x) = 0 for x >1

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could it be said differently if $f$ had no sharp turns on the interval?

Comment: @bryanjaeho yes

Comment: whats wront with my answer? Did i miss something?